# Need to select two lines then add HTML around those lines

Tags: html, regex

Im trying to turn text into an HTML table and im stuck on the  part to separate rows.

Lets say I started with text that was displayed like this:

> 1: a
>
> 2: w
>
> 3: p

Then with a little bit of REGEX I turned it into

```
<td>1</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>w</td>
<td>3</td>
<td>p</td>
```

Now how (with REGEX) would I turn that into this:

```
<tr>
  <td>1</td>
  <td>a</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>2</td>
  <td>w</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>3</td>
  <td>p</td>
</tr>
```

*The indents are just there so you can see it better, I dont actually want it to add them.*

So somehow I would make it look for

```
<td>[0-9]
```

Then select that and the next line then add the  and  to it by doing

```
<td>\1<\td>
```

But I dont know how to do that entirely, if anyone can understand that mess could you help me please? D:

**Edit:** Worked it out!

I started with

> 1: a
>
> 2: w
>
> 3: p

Then I did this:

```
Find: ": "
Replace: "\r\n"
```

Then

```
Find: "([0-9])"
Replace: "<td>\1<td>"
```

Then

```
Find: "^([^<]+)$"
Replace: ""
```

Then

```
Find: "(<td>[0-9]</td>)[\r][\n]"
Replace: "\1"
```

Huehuehue, then

```
Find: "^(.*<td>[0-9]*+)$"
Replace: "<tr>\1</tr>"
```

There was probably a MUCH easier way to do this, but I finally got it :D

Comment: do you always have the same number of lines?

Comment: which language are you using to process the text?

Comment: Your first regex should convert the initial text into 3 lines:<td>1</td><td>a</td>
<td>2</td><td>w</td>
<td>3</td><td>p</td>
Then the problem becomes relatively simple.

Comment: My tip is to do it all in one regex, because there you have already matched the correct groups.

Comment: Oh, and please show us your actual code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first regex should convert the initial text into 3 lines, not 6 as you show:

```
<td>1</td><td>a</td>
<td>2</td><td>w</td>
<td>3</td><td>p</td>
```

Then the problem becomes relatively simple.

Comment: Well, it depends on your tools,  but I'm assuming you're starting with three lines

Comment: I suppose it would be something like '[0-9]</td>[\r][\n]' then replacing only the \r\n in it but I dont know how to do that.


**Edit:** Nevermind got it, im going to work it out now!